# Питон. Не понимаю части кода цикла

Tags: python

В задании необходимо возвести целое положительное число в степень указанного пользователем отрицательного числа, пользоваться возведением в степень нельзя было. Поскольку возводим число в отрицательную степень, был использован цикл 1/x, но я не понимаю, что означает "*=" в строке res *= 1 / x

```
x = float(input("Введите положительное число (x): "))
y = int(input("Введите отрицательное число (y): "))
def my_func (x, y):
    try:
        if x <= 0:
            return "x должен быть положительным"
        if y >= 0:
            return "y должен быть отрицательным"
        else:
            res = 1
            for i in range(abs(y)):
                **res *= 1 / x**    # что значит *= в данном случае??? 
            return {round(res, 4)}
    except ValueError:
        return "Неверный формат числа"
print(my_func(x, y))
```

Comment: Уточните заголовок вопроса [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res *= 1 / x
```

это тоже самое что и:

```
res = res * (1 / x)
```

Comment: @na4os тогда примите его(галочка слева от ответа)